# Trouble Install web3.py for Windows

Tags: python, web3py

I would like to inquire about how to install web3.py by using Windows OS. I have a problem installing the web3.py.

[This is a screen shot when I install web3.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDfxT.png)

I think the error lies in the not yet installed Visual C ++ Build Tools. But when I go to the web link from that provided by the install error, I can not open it.

Please help me to help me in using or installing package web3.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in the error is dead.

You can install Visual C++ Build Tools from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15#)

Comment: Thank you for your response Agile_Eagle, Whether to use visual studio? if so, then i will install the package (visual c ++ build tools) in visual studio.

Comment: @RakaWidhiAntoro yes you need to install it